# Como reiniciar mis variables al presionar el botón una sola vez en flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

estoy elaborando un proyecto en flutter de una app sencilla pero tengo el problema es que al hacer una consulta a mi base de datos en firebase tengo que presionar dos veces el botón para que mis variable se actualicen y el cambio se vea reflejado

este es el codigo que tengo

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProducotsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProducotsPageState createState() => _ProducotsPageState();
}

class _ProducotsPageState extends State<ProducotsPage> {
  TextEditingController _nombreBuscar;
  String nombreproducto = '';
  String valorunitario = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    _nombreBuscar = TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }

  void read() async {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
    try {
      documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('inventario')
          .doc(_nombreBuscar.text)
          .get();
      print('____');
      print(_nombreBuscar);
      print(documentSnapshot.get('nombreproducto'));
      print(documentSnapshot.get('valorunitario'));
      nombreproducto = documentSnapshot.get('nombreproducto');
      valorunitario = documentSnapshot.get('valorunitario');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Productos',
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'ConcertOne', fontSize: 50),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff00171f),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff00171f),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 600,
              height: 73,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _nombreBuscar,
                autofocus: true,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    decorationColor: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Nombre del Producto',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontFamily: 'ConcertOne',
                    color: Color(0xffdee2e6),
                  ),
                  hoverColor: Colors.black,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Text(
              'Buscar',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'Coustard'),
            ),
            color: Color(0xffb48f18),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  read();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 700,
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                              color: Color(0xffb48f18),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/inventario',
                                    arguments: nombreproducto);
                              }),
                        ),
                        Text('Producto: $nombreproducto',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: 'Coustard',
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            color: Color(0xffb48f18),
                            onPressed: () {}),
                      ),
                      Text('Valor: $valorunitario',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'Coustard',
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

el problema es que tengo que darle dos veces al botón para poder ver los cambios reflejados en los Text

y quisiera que al darle al boton BUSCAR una sola vez me traiga todos los datos del firebase(que eso lo hace bien) pero que también me actualice las variables de mis campos Text para que se vean los cambios relejados en un solo toque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `setState` no va al momento que llamas al método, sino luego de que Firebase te retornó la respuesta.

Aquí no:

```dart
 onPressed: () {
             
                  read();
               
            },
```

```dart
  void read() async {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
    try {
      documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('inventario')
          .doc(_nombreBuscar.text)
          .get();
      print('____');
      print(_nombreBuscar);
      print(documentSnapshot.get('nombreproducto'));
      print(documentSnapshot.get('valorunitario'));
      nombreproducto = documentSnapshot.get('nombreproducto');
      valorunitario = documentSnapshot.get('valorunitario');

      //aquí si
        setState(
                () {
     });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bro me fue de mucha ayuda me sirvio de maravilla

Comment: dale, te invito a mi canal para cosas más avanzadas de flutter www.youtube.com/diegoveloper :)